# req.body returns oddly formatted object when posting to API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, object

I'm using Express to create an API to use for my website. When I post an object to the API, it returns as this:

```js
[Object: null prototype] {
  type: 'report',
  'data[id]': '123456',
  'data[dateRequested]': '2021-11-05',
  'data[dateOfService]': '2021-11-11',
  'data[completed]': 'true',
}
```

How could I fix this or turn it into an actual object that I can parse?

Comment: So how are you returning it? We can not guess at what you are doing that causes this to happen. Show your code.

Comment: Are you using body-parser middleware?

Comment: @epascarello I'm using fetch to post it to the API. For now I'm just using console.log() to see if everything is fine.

Comment: Show us the code that is posting the object to the API.  That's likely where the problem is.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan Yes, I am

Comment: @jfriend00 
```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/new', {
  method: 'POST'
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({type: "report", data: {id: "123456", dateRequested: "2021-11-05", dateOfService: "2021-11-11", completed: true}}),
})
```

Comment: Well, this part of what you said your request was: `method: 'POST' headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',` is missing a comma after `'POST'`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry, that was my bad.

Comment: What does that mean?  Does that mean the missing comma was actually the problem?  Or does it mean that was just a local typo only in your comment and not in the code?

Comment: It was just a typo in the comment.

Comment: Well, it appears that something is not making or parsing the JSON in this request properly.  I would suggest going into the Network tab of the Chrome debugger and look at EXACTLY what the browser client is sending over the network to your server for this specific `fetch()` request.  This will tell you if the problem is in constructing the JSON to send to the server or if the problem is in parsing the JSON on your server and will then know where to insert more code diagnostics.

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem! :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.